# Parsing column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, dataframe

I have columns Name with this values:

```
NY0528_3
NY5366_2
4536
NY1244_5
5363
PH1734_3
```

Desired output:

```
0528
5366
6363
1244
5363
1734
```

Whatever I've tried, I can't get a universal solution, but I need that cause I have 200.000 rows. 
Thanks

Comment: Why `6363` in the third row? Shouldn't it be `4536`?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans Yes, my bad while copying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract):

```
df.Name.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Output:

```
0    0528
1    5366
2    4536
3    1244
4    5363
5    1734
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: This one gives me an error :  "['0' '0' '0001' ..., '44357' '44356' '44357'] not in index" .  , do you know what this could be?

Comment: What's the structure of your data frame?

Comment: Pandas dataframe with 20+ columns and a few thousands of rows. 
That column is called  "Name ln".

Answer (score 2):

try using regular expressions:

```
import re

def clean(teststring):
    return re.findall(r"[0-9]{4,4}", teststring)
```

if your data is in `df.col` run:

```
df.col.apply(clean)
```